# Better way to tune query (avoiding subquery) oracle

Tags: oracle12c

I have three tables

1)***

### Employee

---

**Empid**    **Empname**
       1              R
       2              S
       3     T

### 2) Department

Deptid     empid      deptdetlsid
  1          1            1
  1  2 1
  2 1 2

### 3)deptdetails

Deptdetailsid deptname
1 Finance
2 sales

an employee can belong to multiple departments.or may be a new joiner whose dept hasn't been allocated yet. 
I'm writing a query to get list of all employees,if their dept is finance return finance  ,else a null value is populated.

The query I have written is

```
Select empid,empname,deptname from employee,department,
(select deptdetailsid from deptdetails where deptname ='Finance')deptdetails
where Employee.empid =Department.empid(+)
And department.deptdetailsid = deptdetails.deptdetailsid (+)
```

Is there anyway to avoid the subquery and do it more effectively?

Comment: I think you would get more/better help if you took the time to tabulate your example data in a more readable format.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need to avoid a subquery, but it appears you may be looking for another left join...

```
Select employee.empid, employee.empname, department.deptname  
from employee
   left outer join department on (employee.empid = department.empid)
   left outer join deptdetails on (deptdetails.deptdetailsid = departement.deptdetailsid and deptdetails.deptname = 'Finance');
```